# Python readline empty lines

Tags: python, serial-port, readline

I would like to read serial port with python, and print result with readline, but I'm getting empty lines between all result lines. Can you tell me how can I delete all empty lines?

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial
import time
import sys

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600)

print ser.readline()
print ser.readline()
print ser.readline()
print ser.readline()
print ser.readline()
```

I tried few answers from behind but still got empty lines. My txt file looks like:

```
T:  59.30%  22.20 8% 11% N 

T:  59.80%  22.20 8% 11% N 

T:  59.80%  22.20 8% 11% N 

T:  59.80%  22.20 8% 11% N
```

but I need file like:

```
T:  59.30%  22.20 8% 11% N 
T:  59.80%  22.20 8% 11% N 
T:  59.80%  22.20 8% 11% N 
T:  59.80%  22.20 8% 11% N
```

EDIT:

Found way to fix that problem:

```
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-2]
```

It works fine now. This -2 delete /n and that's all.

Comment: Hello. Do you need a file or a displaying of file like you show ?

Comment: I need to read from serial (2 sec) and write to file without empty lines.

Comment: Is **serial** form **pyserial 2.6** (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial/2.6) ? Before to write something wrong, I try to understand what is the nature of **ser**. It seems it isn't a file, is it ?

Comment: wrt/ your edit: you want `line.strip()`, not `line[:-2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

```
import serial

with serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600) as ser:
    for line in ser:
        print line.rstrip('\n')
```

or

```
import serial

with serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600) as ser:
    for line in ser:
        print line,
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    do_something_with(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [these tips](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/298310-new-to-python-serial-readout/), this should do:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600)

while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    if line:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM11', 115200, timeout = 0.01)
print("Starting up")
while True:
    try:
        line = ser.readline().decode('ascii').strip()
        if line:
            print (line)
    except:
        pass
    ser.flush()
```